# Why do I have to --force my git commits

Tags: git, git-push

i have several git repositories set up and everytime i setup a new one and i do the first commit and push, this command fails `git push origin master` and i get some error about how it failed to push some refs.

```
----@--------- /c/git/repo/---- (master)
$ git push origin master
--------------------------------
--------------------------------
To -----------------------------
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/-----/----.git'
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.  See the
'Note about fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details.
```

however if i do a `git push --force origin master` it works, why is that and why do i have to do it everytime?

Comment: It looks like the repositories you are pushing to are not empty. Every time you force push commits, you overwrite anything that was on the server, but not on your local PC. I'd be careful about that.

Comment: that's what i am fearful of, but i am sure i created the repo without any files and still..

Comment: You are pushing to github. Have you actually created a new project on github, or are you always pushing to the same remote?

Comment: to the new project, i created a new remote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error...

```
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
```

...means that the remote repository has changes that are not yet in your repository.  If you are creating a repository on GitHub, it's possible to create a non-empty repository if you ask GitHub to pre-populate your repository with a `.gitignore` or `README` file.

In any case, when you see this error, rather than using `--force` (which will overwrite any changes in the remote repository), you should probably just run:

```
git pull
```

This will bring down any changes and merge them into your local repository, at which point a `git push` should work just fine.

You can also clone the remote repository to another directory and inspect it's contents if you're not sure what's there.